# Website with test data files for specific algorithms/data structures?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, coding

Is there any website, like [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl) and [Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net), with the test data files available for specific algorithms/data structures?

I know it's a fun challenge to solve those problems on your own, but I am looking for test data files where the algorithm/data structure to use are explicitly mentioned.

"Implement a linked list and do this and that with the data to confirm!", 
"Implement a hash tree and do this and that with the data to confirm!" etc.

Answer (score 4):

The [Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) has a dozen of tasks with input file, expected results and solutions in many programming languages.

For example, the [k-nucleotide benchmark](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=knucleotide) (Hashtable update and k-nucleotide strings) is defined like this:

```
We use FASTA files generated by the fasta benchmark as input for this benchmark. 
Note: the file may include both lowercase and uppercase codes.

Each program should 

 1. read line-by-line a redirected FASTA format file from stdin
 2. extract DNA sequence THREE
 3. define a procedure/function to update a hashtable of k-nucleotide keys and count
    values, for a particular reading-frame — even though we'll combine k-nucleotide
    counts for all reading-frames (grow the hashtable from a small default size)
 4. use that procedure/function and hashtable to
   - count all the 1-nucleotide and 2-nucleotide sequences, and write the code and 
     percentage frequency, sorted by descending frequency and then ascending 
     k-nucleotide key
   - count all the 3- 4- 6- 12- and 18-nucleotide sequences, and write the count and
     code for the specific sequences GGT GGTA GGTATT GGTATTTTAATT GGTATTTTAATTTATAGT
```